# How to execute multiple functions in google apps script in order?

Tags: google-apps-script

Thanks in advance for your time here. I am self taught and new to coding, hence apologies if the question below is something an average programmer should already know.

I have created multiple functions in a single gas file, which when run individually calculate various aspects of same expenses data. But I need all functions to run in order to reach my end goal, which unfortunately I am unable to achieve. Please see examples below.

1. Both functions when Run individually work without issues.

   ```
   function totalSpend(){
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var rt = ss.getRange("K2").getValue();
   var pt = ss.getRange("K1").getValue();
   var ts =  rt + pt ;
   ss.getRange("K3").setValue(ts); }

   function perHead(){
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var ts = ss.getRange("K3").getValues();
   var ph = ts / 2;
   ss.getRange("K4").setValue(ph);}
   ```
2. But if I combine them both under a single function and then run, nothing happens. I tried using debugger and Execution Transcript but didn't have any luck. Below is example which doesn't work.

   ```
   function expCalc(){

   function totalSpend(){
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var rt = ss.getRange("K2").getValue();
   var pt = ss.getRange("K1").getValue();
   var ts =  rt + pt ;
   ss.getRange("K3").setValue(ts); };

   function perHead(){
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var ts = ss.getRange("K3").getValues();
   var ph = ts / 2;
   ss.getRange("K4").setValue(ph);};

   }
   ```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
function expCalc(){
  totalSpend();
  perHead();
}

function totalSpend(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var rt = ss.getRange("K2").getValue();
var pt = ss.getRange("K1").getValue();
var ts =  rt + pt ;
ss.getRange("K3").setValue(ts); }

function perHead(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var ts = ss.getRange("K3").getValues();
var ph = ts / 2;
ss.getRange("K4").setValue(ph);}
```

or

```
function expCalc(){

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var rt = ss.getRange("K2").getValue();
var pt = ss.getRange("K1").getValue();
var ts =  rt + pt ;
ss.getRange("K3").setValue(ts);

var ts = ss.getRange("K3").getValues();
var ph = ts / 2;
ss.getRange("K4").setValue(ph);
}
```